# Making in app purchase available for Mac & iOS

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I've got app for iOS and Mac which has all functionality unlocked with single in app purchase.

But now it's separate in app purchase on Mac & Separate for iOS. I wonder if it's possible to have one in app purchase which could unlock both iOS and Mac.

Update: I wonder if Apple provides mechanism for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you need your server where you could track licenses. Many apps do that e.g. like Office 365.

Comment: Hello, might update the question then. I was wondering if Apple provides architecture for that. (Like being able to read in app purchases from the same iTunes account)